# Какой протокол указывать на порту роутера

Tags: системное-программирование

просветленные..

Вопрос такой:
Есть роутер в котором порт смотрит наружу, у него нужно указать протокол tcp или udp.
Я подключаюсь, например, по vpn через этот порт, который приходит на другой роутер.
Так вот, какая разница, какой протокол я указал на внешнем порту, если внутри фреймов уже указан нужный протокол, который указал само приложение, которое  взаимодействует внутри конечного lan?

Comment: Что значит "подключаюсь по vpn" через порт ? У вас внутри сети стоит vpn сервер и вы хотите пробросить на него этот порт что бы к этому vpn могли подключаться ? Если так, то указываете тот протокол с помощью которого реализован ваш vpn. А если это не так, то уточните что вы имеете ввиду, что вы вообще настраиваете на вашем роутере

Comment: Вот вы правильно уловили)). У меня этот порт как-бы шлюзом выступает для следующего роутера, к которому я по впн подключаюсь.

Comment: vpn разные бывают, работающие по разным протоколам. Попробуйте для начала tcp, больше вероятность что он на нем. udp я практически не встречал. Но бывают vpn (причем очень распространенные, используемые в винде) которые используют протокол pptp. Это отдельный протокол уровня tcp или udp и в нем например вообще нет понятия 'порт'. И его невозможно пробросить через стандартные средства проброски портов которые бывают на обычных роутерах (надо пробрасывать порт 1723/tcp и еще 47 протокол отдельно). Если у вас так, то вам надо пробрасывать весь трафик на второй роутер (см. настройки DMZ)